# aligning text to full width and equal automatic spacing

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have N words. For example the following;

- Dog
- Peanut
- Oranges
- Lemon
- Disciplinary

All these words have different lengths.

Let's say I have a container width some variable width X (The container may scale with the page).

What I want is to align the words on a horizontal line with with N-1 equal spacings between the words. There should be no spacing on the left side of the leftmost word, and no spacing on the right side of the rightmost word. The left side of the leftmost word should tangent/touch the left side of the container, and the right side of the rightmost word should tangent/touch the right side of the container.

Here is an image of how I would like it to look.

[image]

What would be the best way to implement this using html/css/js?

My first thought have been;

- calc(expression): but I dont know the width of the text?
- margin: 0 auto: but does this work with multiple elements? What about browser support?
- CSS flexbox: I dont have much experience with this.
- Some smart js implementation: how?

Note: I did see this thread. It's similar, but not quite what I'm looking for;

[Equal and full width navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032414/equal-and-full-width-navigation)

Comment: I mean... https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a `<span>` around each word, you can give the parent:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
```

All items will receive equal space between them, and given a lack of space will break onto a second line.